# Move document library with versions and permissions

Tags: 2016

I have two site collections in the same web application.

One of documents library in the first site collection need to be moved to the second site collection with versions and permissions setting

Is it possible to use content structure feature to move document library  between two site collections? If no, Please provide me the right direction to acheive my need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a licensed version of ShareGate or Metalogix then it is easy as pie, otherwise you might be able to use a trial version of Metalogix if the size of the libraries is less than the size limit for the trial.

Comment: Great, any script or c# code to do that

Comment: There are some projects on github that can do some of it, like move the content inc versions, but so far I haven't found one that takes care of permissions as well

Comment: Could you please share links for these projects

Comment: I reviewed two of them a year ago but both fell short of what I needed so I just recommended that my clients finds the 4k for a license as it would cost more to have me patching the gaps in the free versions. Sorry, I don't remember the names of those projects but Google is you friend